# Nhibernate transaction locks a tabel

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions

I have developed a WCF api which is using nHibernate. I am new to this. I have used session.update to take care of transaction. I have a for loop in which based on select condition I am updating a record ie. If A is present in tabel1 then I am updating the table else inserting a new entry.

I am getting "could not execute query." when trying to execute a select query on a table which was previously being updated by adding a new entry in the table.

What I think is, because I am using session.save(table1) and then trying select entries from that table I am getting an error. Since session.save temporarily locks the table I am not able to execute a select query on that table.

What can be the solution on this?

**Update**:
This the for loop I am using to check in the database for some field:

```
using (ITransaction tranx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
   savefunction();
   tranx.Commit();
}
```

Save function:

```
public void savefunction()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.Count; i++)
    {             
                    ICandidateAttachmentManager candidateAttach = new ManagerFactory().GetCandidateAttachmentManager();
                    CandidateAttachment attach = new CandidateAttachment();
                    attach = checkCV();
         if(attach == null)
         {
           //insert new entry into table attach
            session.save(attach);
         }
      }
}
```

checkCV function:

```
public void checkCV()
{
        using (ICandidateAttachmentManager CandidateAttachmentManager = new ManagerFactory().GetCandidateAttachmentManager())
        {
           IList<CandidateAttachment> lstCandidateAttachment = CandidateAttachmentManager.GetByfkCandidateId(CandidateId);
            if (lstCandidateAttachment.Count > 0)
            {
                CandidateAttachment attach = lstCandidateAttachment.Where(x => x.CandidateAttachementType.Id.Equals(FileType)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (attach != null)
                {
                   return null;
                }
                else
                {
                   return "some string";
                }
            }
        }
}
```

What happening here is in the for loop if say for i=2 the attach value comes to null that I am entering new entry into attach table. Then for i=3 when it enters checkCV function I get an error at this line:

> IList lstCandidateAttachment =
>   CandidateAttachmentManager.GetByfkCandidateId(CandidateId);

I think it is because since I am using session.save and then trying to read the tabel contents I am unable to execute the query and table is locked till I commit my session. Between the beginTransaction and commit, the table associated with the object is locked. How can I achieve this? Any Ideas?

**Update:**
I read up on some of the post. It looks like I need to set isolation level for the transaction. But even after adding it doesn't seem to work. Here is how I tried to inplement it:

```
 using (ITransaction tranx = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
 {
     saveDocument();
 }
```

Comment: Post some code just to ilustrate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

something I don't understand in your code is where you get your nHibernate session.

Indeed you use

```
    new ManagerFactory().GetCandidateAttachmentManager();
```

and

```
    using (ICandidateAttachmentManager CandidateAttachmentManager = new ManagerFactory().GetCandidateAttachmentManager())
```

so your ManagerFactory class provides you the ISession ?

then you do:

```
    CandidateAttachment attach = new CandidateAttachment();
    attach = checkCV();
```

but

```
    checkCV() returns either a null or a string ?
```

Finally you should never do

```
    Save()
```

but instead

```
    SaveOrUpdate()
```

Hope that helps you resolving your issue.

Feel free to give more details

Comment: I have updated my question please take a look. The for loop is in the fuction savefunction(), and I have done begin transaction before calling savefunction().