# How to read uncommitted data in nHibernate transaction?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions, isolation-level, read-uncommitted

I would like to know to know how to read uncommitted data. I have an application which is saving an entry into table1 and then tries to read some entry from same table. I am unable to do that because the data gets locked between begin transaction and end transaction.

I read up on the net and I feel that by seting isolationlevel= ReadUnCommitted, I should be able to handle it. But It doesn't seem to work.

Please refer to my earlier post to get more details: [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957233/nhibernate-transaction-locks-a-tabel)

Comment: Here is my solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302746/how-do-add-nolock-with-nhibernate/39518098#39518098

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use SQL Server , since in Oracle and some others ReadUncommitted is not supported.
For sql server, ReadUncommitted should work. Alternatively you can send an adhoc query from nhibernate and add **with (nolock)** to your query and it will read uncommitted data

Comment: Yes I am using SQL server. Can you please give me more details on `send adhoc query and add nolock`. How can I do that? I am new to nHibernate. Please provide some link to refer to.